# Построение маршрута c использованием gmap.net

Tags: c#, google-maps-api, google-maps

В приложении на C#, с использованием библиотеки Gmap.net необходимо построить маршрут между двумя точками. При этом формирую запрос на сервер в таком виде:

```
string url = string.Format(
    "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin={0},&destination={1}&sensor=false&language=ru&mode={2}",
    Uri.EscapeDataString("Днепропетровск, Семафорная 42"),
    Uri.EscapeDataString("Днепропетровск, площадь Старомостовая"),
    Uri.EscapeDataString("driving"));
```

Если задавать адрес начальной и конечной точек, то все рассчитывается и отрисовывается идеально. Мне необходимо задавать не адрес, а широту и долготу данных точек. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Как написано в документации](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters) Google Maps API в origin и destiniton необходимо просто подставить свои координаты, к примеру:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=41.43206,-81.38992&destination=41.43206,-81.39992
```